# How to bring up an Explorer window in the current Cygwin shell folder?

Tags: shell, windows-explorer, cygwin

I'm in a shell session in Cygwin, and want to open up a Windows Explorer window in the current directory you're in. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

#### The easy way

```
cygstart .
```

#### The smart-ass way

```
explorer "$(cygpath -d "$(pwd)")"
```

This takes the current directory, converts it from the Cygwin to the Windows format, then passes it as the argument to the explorer program.

Comment: also `explorer .`

Comment: @matzeri: Even though `.` is a Cygwin, not a Windows, path?

Comment: it is the same. In both the dot means the current directory